# how to count and display realtime database queries using ajax and PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, ajax

It gives great effect when you stream info in real time using ajax. for this example a SEO / webgrader tool called [www.teqpad.com](http://teqpad.com) gives a nice interface and real time information on each queries into its database. They use PHP/ajax for the purpose.

My questions are:

- how do they do it?
- What are the methods or steps to take care of?
- How php need to be written in to show the same.

I am not asking code but the method or proceedure to write the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which specific features do you want to know about? Real time information on that site is probably collected using a web crawler.

Comment: From your description i think you already know the method / procedure. What do you really want to know?

Comment: actually how to interact php with ajax and how to write php script to work with..

Answer (score 1):

Use the javascript `setTimeout()` function to invoke GET requests to the server.
Server returns data from your database.
HTML is updated.

Comment: Sory. What do you mean? What periods?

Answer (score 0):

You do an AJAX call every few seconds with javascript and refresh the HTML of the page with the response of the call.

You could use JQuery to do the AJAX calls: 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

The call can be done to a PHP script. Depending the kind of information you want to get is the kind of operations you do on PHP.

Here is a simple example: http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp